# assign a value based on another column's value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataset `df`that looks like this:

```
code
Germany
Italy
Germany
France
```

I want to create a new column

```
df['status']
```

and assign it values based on the `code` column. Wherever, the code is Germany, I want to assign `df['status']` the value "ON". Everywhere else, I want to write "OFF". How can I achieve this?

I some solutions using `.apply()`but I read that there are slower, which is why I am looking for alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

You can use masking:

```py
# Create column with default value
df["status"] = "OFF"

# Change value based on mask value
df.loc[df["code"] == "Germany", "status"] = "ON"
```

And I would use `True` and `False` instead of `"ON"` and `"OFF"`, it saves some memory and it is a generally better code practice.